Liquid simulation inside an object
I want to create a simulation where liquid interacts within the object lets say cube, so when i drop it from some height it should interacts accordingly ,it can be done by using flip fluid addon ,but i want to learn how to simulate without using addon
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C7WVXzJ7aY&t=519s&pp=ygUraG93IHRvIGNyZWF0ZSBpbnRlcmFjdGl2ZSBsaXF1aWQgaW4gYmxlbmRlcg%3D%3D

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
